# Java, Copy Size of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I just took up Java and was wondering. Let's say I have an array (in my case multidimensional) and I wanted to make a copy of it but using a different variable, e.g. I have a boolean array

`boolean[][] arrBool = [2][3]`

and I wanted to create an int array of the same dimensions

`int[][] arrInt= [2][3]`

array. What would the simplest way to do this be?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `length`, it returns the length of an array

```
int[][] arrInt = new int[arrBool.length][arrBool[0].length]
```

Comment: A minimum explaination may be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Just as you'd think you would

```
boolean[][] arrBool = new boolean[2][3];
int[][] arrInt = new int[2][3];
```

But I guess you probably mean what if the dimensions are dynamic. Then you could do

```
boolean[][] arrBool = ...;
int[][] arrInt = new int[arrBool.length][arrBool[0].length];
```